# Can't use @ in jquery in MVC Razor page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working with MVC4 Razor pages, in page I have one code block for jquery. In my script file I have one function like

```
 fucntion MyAjaxRequest(ClickedElement, RequestType, RequestUrl, PostParentForm, PostformID,RequestData,ReturnFunction){}
```

from this function I send ajax request to call controller method. To specify which controller and controller method to be call I am passing value in RequestUrl parameter like

```
@section JSSection{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.star-icon').click(function () {

        MyAjaxRequest(this, 'get', 'Url.Action("MethodNameOfController", "ControllerName")', null, null, { EmailID: $(this).attr('value') }, 
     function (result, clickedElement) {

         if (result.ResponseData == "False") {

             $(clickedElement).removeClass("star-icon stared").addClass("star-icon unstared");

         }
         else if (result.ResponseData == "True") {

             $(clickedElement).removeClass("star-icon unstared").addClass("star-icon stared");

         }
         else {

         }

     });
    });

</script>
}
```

but in this case its not working properly because I need to add @ before Url.Action(.... like

```
   @section JSSection{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.star-icon').click(function () {

        MyAjaxRequest(this, 'get', '@Url.Action("MethodNameOfController", "ControllerName")', null, null, { EmailID: $(this).attr('value') }, 
     function (result, clickedElement) {

         if (result.ResponseData == "False") {

             $(clickedElement).removeClass("star-icon stared").addClass("star-icon unstared");

         }
         else if (result.ResponseData == "True") {

             $(clickedElement).removeClass("star-icon unstared").addClass("star-icon stared");

         }
         else {

         }

     });
    });

</script>
}
```

but problem is that when I use @ in jquery code it will close section early before  tag and not consider

```
);
</script>
}
```

Can anybody tell me how can I solve this?

Comment: Try escaping @ like this @@

Comment: I tried it also but Escaping also not working. Still its closing block early.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the url into a javascript variable and then passing that to your function.

You may be able to debug better afterwards.

```
$('.star-icon').click(function ()
{
    var url = '@Url.Action("MethodNameOfController", "ControllerName")';

    MyAjaxRequest(this, 'get', url, null, null, { EmailID: $(this).attr('value') }, 
 function (result, clickedElement) {
```